# Launching Keycloak 20.0.3 on REL 7.9 in a Docker container with compose never responds to HTTP requests

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I have an application that uses Keycloak 15.0.0 on REL 7.9 and other OSes (REL 8.7, Ubuntu 22.04, Oracle Linux 8.7). I am running this behind NGINX proxy and have it 100% working with Keycloak 15.0.0 and have for about a year 1/2 now.  Now, we need to update to Keycloak 20.0 for OpenJDK issues and such. I updated my image in the docker compose YML configuration, my environment variables that all changed by this v20.0, and launched my application to have it update.

On 3 of the 4 OSes this worked 100% fine, came up great, came up quick, love the v20.0 UI changes in Keycloak. I tried this on FIPS enabled and FIPS disabled setups, and all worked 100%. It works as expected with my application, behind NGINX, and no issues at all whatsoever we have found in the last two weeks.

However, on Red Hat 7.9 for whatever reason I get no logs at all and nothing happens. I can do a `docker exec -it xxxxxx /bin/sh` type of command and get into it, but even a `curl http://localhost:8080/auth/` turns up just a connection refused. It is almost like it is not running.

This happens whether I am updating a Keycloak 15.0.0 already setup, or if I remove that docker volume and start over from scratch. It just hangs there and does nothing.

And this only happens on REL 7.9. The other operating systems work great after a few minutes and respond correctly. I have even left it alone for up to 30 minutes to see if there was a process running, something hidden, a timeout, something else as a "ghost in the machine". But still nothing works.

I have searched for a while, read the readme files on updates, and started over fresh on other OSes and they all work. Just not this one. So looking for guidance here on what to change/try. Or I cannot use Keycloak 20.0 on REL 7.9. Until its EOL June 2024.

The keycloak configuration that works on the other 3 OSes, with the same docker versions installed and all the same permissions setup via our Ansible setup, is below. I cannot figure out why REL 7.9 is the one holdout on this.

Any help or tips or things to try is much appreciated. I am 8+ hours into this with nothing to show.

```
  keycloak:
    image: keycloak-mybuild:20.0.3
    restart: on-failure:5
    container_name: keycloak
    command: start --optimized 
    ports:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/xxxxxxxx
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=xxxxxxxx
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth
      - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
      - KC_HTTP_PORT=8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - namednetwork
```

Comment: Part of my problem, not doing the build mentioned at https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers and making sure I specify the postgres DB type in the build. That fixes the coming up slow on all other 3 OSes I was running into. And in my docker compose YML using the `    command: start --optimized` as well since I set my entrypoint in the Dockerfile per the URL above.  STILL have the issue of this not starting AT ALL on REL 7.9. Starts well on the other 3 OSes. I updated the information above on the latest fixes so far.

Comment: Hey Dale, I have been facing the same issue when I have fips enabled.
First check if you have fips enabled -> cat /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
 if it returns 1 fips is enabled. Add the following to your environment variable to disable it. JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dcom.redhat.fips=false". I have yet to figure out how to start keycloak with fips enabled.

Comment: Thank you @JayC on my REL 7.9 box I do have FIPS enabled. I am running this all in a container. Can I add the KC_FIPS_MODE new variable to the ENV in KC 20? Have you tried that? I need to test that.   And is that "JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dcom.redhat.fips=false" in the KC environment listing?

Comment: Please note this is an workaround. Here are links related to issue https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/9916 and https://www.keycloak.org/2022/11/fips

Comment: Yes @JayC understood. And we will be watching this as it progresses with the FIPS implementation. I have tested this on REL 8.7 with FIPS enabled on the OS using podman, and no need to do the JAVA_OPTS_APPEND. So far, only REL 7.9 which is EOL June 2024.

Answer (score 3):

Voila!!

That line that @jayc talked on `- JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dcom.redhat.fips=false"` was the answer. Thank you so much! This worked on my REL 7.9 box with FIPS enabled 100% every time, with the Keycloak 20.0.3 container I built from the steps mentioned on containers https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers.

```
keycloak:
    image: keycloak-mybuild:20.0.3
    restart: on-failure:5
    container_name: keycloak
    command: start --optimized 
    ports:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/xxxxxxxx
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=xxxxxxxx
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth
      - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
      - KC_HTTP_PORT=8080
      - JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dcom.redhat.fips=false"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - namednetwork
```

Comment: This solved my problem.   I was able to import my realm too!  command: start --optimized --import-realm

Comment: Can you give example of Dockerfile too for building the keycloak image if possible. Was it exactly same as in the documentation

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile if it's fine

Comment: Figured out. Thanks with this answer though I had to add `command: start --optimized --proxy edge` as I was using reverse proxy